# Is Mysior's example completely Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

In the article

> *Mysior, A.*, [**A regular space which is not completely regular**](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1981-0601748-4), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 81, 652-653 (1981). [ZBL0451.54019](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0451.54019).

there is an example of the space that is regular, but not completely regular. Such spaces can be completely Hausdorff (space, where any two points can be separated by a continuous function) and can not be. I am interested in whether the space from the article is completely Hausdorff or not, and how to prove it.

Comment: You read the final comment about adding a second point to get a non-competely Hausdorff space? This strongly suggests to me that the first space is completely Hausdorff.

Comment: In the remark, there is written that if we add point to X, that the result space is not completely Hausedorff. How we can prove that?

Comment: Because all continuous functions give the same value to the two points, so we cannot separate them by a function.

Comment: Yes, its clear. I am interested in, how to prove that all continuous functions give the same value.

Comment: The same way, presumably, as is used to show $a$ and $A$ give the same value..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, $X$ is completely Hausdorff.  There are two nontrivial cases: separating two points of $\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$ and separating a point of $\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$ and $a$.  For both of these cases, observe that for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ the set  $U_x=\{(x,0)\}\cup I_x\cup I_x'$ is clopen in $X$.  Thus the characteristic function of $U_x$ is continuous and separates $(x,0)$ from every other point of $\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$ and from $a$.

Comment: Why is $U_x$ closed? I can see why it would be closed for $x$ an integer, since I can construct its complement using the neighborhood of $a$, but I don't see how to show the complement is open for $U_{1/2}$.

Comment: @E-A: I'm not sure how you think $x$ being an integer makes any difference.  For any $y\neq x$, $U_y$ intersects $U_x$ at finitely many points and removing those finitely many points gives a neighborhood of $(y,0)$ disjoint from $U_x$.  For $a$, just take $U_n(a)$ for any $n>x+2$.

Comment: In the remark, there is written that if we add point to X, that the result space is not completely Hausedorff. How we can prove that?