# Mysior's example of not completely Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1981-081-04/S0002-9939-1981-0601748-4/S0002-9939-1981-0601748-4.pdf

In this link, there is the example of regular space, that is not completely regular. This space is also completely Hausdorff ([Is Mysior's example completely Hausdorff?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3516497/is-mysiors-example-completely-hausdorff)). But in the article, the second page is remark, where is written, that if we add one point b to the space, with its local neighborhoods, that the space is also regular and not completely regular, but also not completely Hausdorff, because there is not the continuous function f, for which f(a)=f(b). I am interested in, how to prove that (that this space is not completely Hausdorff).